# Postgres is getting locked on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord, database-deadlocks

I just stumbled upon an error, that I never saw before, nor heard of before. I just deployed an update to production (from staging, where everything went fine) and then I saw, that I received a deadlock from postgres. My SQL queries didn't went through anymore and the API got stuck with

This was an ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError:

```
could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

After I googled some time, I saw that Heroku is offering a simple FAQ for when PostgreSQL is getting locked and there are processes that are needed to be free'd up again. So I went, and checked the processes, this is what I saw:

```
  pid  |        state        |  source   |    username    |   running_for   |       transaction_start       | waiting |                                                                                                                 query
-------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 24358 | active              | bin/rails | xxx            | 00:00:43.026836 | 2021-02-11 15:53:42.672799+00 | t       | INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "full_name", "guest_user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
 24378 | active              | bin/rails | xxx            | 00:00:44.874495 | 2021-02-11 15:53:40.82514+00  | t       | INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "full_name", "guest_user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
 24348 | active              | bin/rails | xxx            | 00:01:01.145712 | 2021-02-11 15:53:24.553923+00 | t       | INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "full_name", "guest_user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
 24347 | idle in transaction | bin/rails | xxx            | 00:01:08.554992 | 2021-02-11 15:53:17.144643+00 | t       | SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4
 24349 | idle in transaction | bin/rails | xxx            | 00:01:34.246178 | 2021-02-11 15:52:51.453457+00 | t       | SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4
(5 rows)
```

After doing what was supposed to be the best solution (killing all processes and re-running the servers) it seems to be running again. However, when I use a new feature (thank god this is not published in the app, yet) I am seeing this weird behavior again.

I think this is super strange behavior, because dead-locks on databases normally only occur, when there are two processes *altering* a column, and not *SELECTing*...

What can I do to remove this and be free to use the database again?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps the pool size could be increased https://help.heroku.com/QH0BE3ND/why-am-i-seeing-activerecord-connectiontimeouterror-could-not-obtain-a-database-connection-from-my-rails-app

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @IronMan. However, I am not sure, if this will solve the problem, since the query is blocking long enough to also kill a bigger pool size.

Comment: Is there some connection between `users` and `active_storage_attachments` like foreign keys, procedures (ruby and/or DB), running together in one transaction-block (might not be apparent right away), ... . Also, what is happening with the returned `id` from the users-query?